# Database of final BA/MA papers?

Tags: publications, masters, bachelor

Is there any open database(s) that offer access to Bachelor or Masters level final papers? Especially interested in top universities and computer science related papers.
The thing is that other day I browsed through BA level papers defended in my university and many of them seemed to be a little too trivial. I'd like to see what is quality of papers produced by those who attend top universities.

Comment: Such an open database of student work would likely run afoul of [FERPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act) in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Increasingly, individual universities are requiring students to submit digital versions of theses (particularly at masters level and above). However, as far as I know this is generally organised by each university individually, often under the auspices of the university library. I am not aware of any large centralised databases, though these might exist for particular subjects. A Google search for "student thesis database" or "student thesis < institution>" seems your best bet.

Do bear in mind that different institutions may have different requirements, particularly in the amount of time students are expected to spend on their thesis project: quality may not be directly comparable!

Answer (score 0):

The database I am most familiar with is the ProQuest Dissertations and Theses Database/UMI, which advertises having nearly 3 million items in it's collection (http://www.proquest.com/products-services/pqdt.html). The University of Texas website reports Proquest receives 90+% of all dissertations completed in the US each year (http://www.lib.utexas.edu/indexes/titles.php?id=114). It allows you to search by a range of criteria, including targeting either Master's or Doctoral papers, or searching by academic subject area.

Many universities include Proquest in their electronic database offerings. My university requires we format our theses and dissertations to be compatible with Proquest, and these are deposited immediately upon graduation, unless embargoed due to pending patents.

I am not aware of a database for Bachelor's level papers.